# YubiKey NFC as authentication method in FIDO using Android?

Tags: android, nfc, chrome-custom-tabs, webauthn, yubikey

I'm not familiar with the FIDO API so I am wondering if there is a way to use/"blip" a NFC key (YubiKey) as authentication method on a website implementing the FIDO API running on an Android device (in chrome browser/custom tabs)? How is this enabled in that case?

It seems the Google native FIDO2 API supports fingerprint and screen lock, but cannot really find any specific info about NFC keys in this case either.

Comment: Logically it should be possible if device is defaulting to Chrome browser as custom tab - `Custom Tabs uses an ACTION_VIEW Intent with key Extras to customize the UI. This means that by default the page will open in the system browser, or the user's default browser.` from https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs. Be aware that non-Google Chrome browsers may not work due to lower level Google Play Services hooks: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/7756